# Redirect with htaccess only for specific folder including all information from within folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this folder, which is supposed to be redirected via htaccess to a new domain like this:

```
olddomain.com/folder/page1 to newdomain.com/folder/page1

olddomain.com/folder/page2 to newdomain.com/folder/page2 , etc.
```

I have tried the following code.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/(.*)$ $1http://www.newdomain.com/folder/$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Problem i have is that i don't get how I can get the specific RewriteCond, which also keeps all the information showcased in the url within the folder. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Gunaseelan yep. tried it i.e. like that:
RewriteRule ^(.*?)%{HTTP_HOST}/folder/(.*)$    $1http://www.newdomain.com/folder/$2  [NC,QSA,L]

But I'm basically just on a trial and error mission with this up to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com/folder$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com/folder$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/folder$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will probably fix your issue.

Comment: thx for the quick shoot, but redirect should only apply to the one specific folder. old domain still exists. only folder has moved.

Comment: i misinterpreted you. putting this into a special htaccess within the folder, solved my probs! thank you so much!